# C# Marshalling a C++ struct with wchar_t* member occasionally leaves the heap corrupted

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

I have declared a `struct` as follows:

```
// C++
struct TestStruct
{
    wchar_t* TestString;
};
```

and the corresponding managed representation

```
// C#
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct TestStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string TestString;
}
```

As well as this function:

```
// C++
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall FillMultipleStructs(TestStruct* testStructures, const short arrayLength)
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        const wchar_t stringToAllocate[] = L"foo";
        const unsigned long size = wcslen(stringToAllocate) * sizeof(wchar_t) + sizeof(wchar_t);
        wchar_t* allocatedString = static_cast<wchar_t*>(::CoTaskMemAlloc(size));
        wcscpy_s(allocatedString, size, stringToAllocate);

        (&testStructures[i])->testString = allocatedString;
    }
}
```

which is called by the `FillMultipleStructs` method, that takes multiple `TestStructs` and initializes them in the C++ code.

```
// C#
[DllImport("the path", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "FillMultipleStructs", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
private static extern void _FillMultipleStructs([In, Out] TestStruct[] structures, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] short arrayLength);

public static IEnumerable<TestStruct> FillMultipleStructs(IEnumerable<TestStruct> structures)
{
    TestStruct[] structuresArray = structures.ToArray();
    _FillMultipleStructs(structuresArray, (short) structuresArray.Length);
    return structuresArray;
}
```

Calling the code works like this:

```
FillMultipleStructs(
    new List<TestStruct>()
    {
        new TestStruct(),
        new TestStruct(),
        new TestStruct()                       
    });
```

---

**Now, the question is**: sometimes, the code works, however, sometimes I get an `a heap has been corrupted` error. I do not understand where that comes from nor why it does work occasionally and sometimes it does not.

I guess it has to do with the marshalling of the `struct`'s string member, so, if anyone can tell me where my error is or if anyone can point me in the right direction or show me the proper way to do that, I would gladly appreciate that.

Comment: 0xC0000374 only applies to the unmanaged heap so marshalling can't have anything to do with it.  Lots of ways C++ code can corrupt the heap, luckily you can just delete this code since it doesn't do anything useful.  One less thing to worry about.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for your answer, since this is a simplified example I could delete the code, but my actual code does something useful, so deleting this is not an option. Further, I found out that the heap corruption error happens in the code that tries to allocate the string using `CoTaskMemAlloc`, but I still do not know how to solve it.

Comment: I believe you would need to Marshall the unmanaged `CoTaskMemAlloc`'d strings into c# strings and then actually free the memory. At least that seems to be my recollection. I don't think you can just treat the unmanaged strings as managed strings.  You can take a look at [this article](https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/returning-an-array-of-strings-from-c-to-c-part-1/), it is dealing with ansi strings but you could easily adapt the code to wide chars. Note it has been a long time since I tried something like this and there may be better ways to do it.

Comment: @pstrjds I also think I have to marshall the strings, but I have no idea on how to do that, since they are not single return values (which would be easy then), but rather members of a `struct`.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow - As I mentioned, it has been a while since I messed with this stuff and I don't have any old sample code lying around (did this stuff 8 years ago at a previous job), but you could try changing the code to marshal as a `BSTR` and then instead of the CoTaskMemAlloc call, create `BSTR` objects. From my recollection, that was the approach we took initially but eventually just wrote a C++/CLI wrapper to bridge the gap. If you can go that direction, that is potentially an easier path.

Comment: @pstrjds thank you, if this was an answer, it would be the accepted answer. This way I managed to get it running perfectly, no heap corruptions anymore and the code executes as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this question struggling with the same problem, to summarize what [pstrjds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416574/pstrjds) already said in a comment:

> marshal as a `BSTR` and then instead of the `CoTaskMemAlloc` call,
>   create `BSTR` objects

which effectively means changing the `C#` `struct`'s definition from

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public string TestString;
```

to

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public string TestString;
```

and instead of using `::CoTaskMemAlloc` to allocate a string in `C++`, `::SysAllocString` needs to be used.

I did not have to change the signature of the `C++` `struct`, since `BSTR` (in my case) was in the end a `typedef` for `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I didn't add as an answer because I was not confident I had remembered correctly.  One thing I would suggest is to change your struct in your real code to mirror the `BSTR` (even though it is just a typedef), this way it is still very clear what is going on when a new dev joins 3 years from now and has to work on this code.