# Create a linux compatible wchar_t* string as char* in c#

Tags: c#, c++

Assuming I have a struct defined in c# (.NET Core)

```
   public struct PARAMS
   {
       public unsafe char* pFileName;
[...]
   }
```

and a C++ struct

```
typedef struct
{
    wchar_t* pwchFileName;
} PARAMS
```

Given a .NET string, how do I create the correct data structure in C#?
The struct is a parameter of a P/Invoke, target operating system is 64 bit Linux. I cannot change any of the structs or the api.
From what I have researched so far, there might be difference between windows
 and linux (utf-16 vs. utf-32)?

Comment: I think you mean `glibc`-compatible. AFAICT Linux (the OS) doesn't care about `wchar_t`. I've got no idea what `wchar_t` is on Android (Linux, but bionic instead of glibc)

Comment: Did you read <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877031/c-sharp-marshalling-a-c-struct-with-wchar-t-member-occasionally-leaves-the-he>

Comment: `wchar_t` is 32-bit on linux. You'd probably want some other type, like `char16_t`.